# How does blender calculate poseBone.matrix?

Tags: scripting, bones

How does blender calculate a poseBone.matrix through the hierarchy chain? 
A bone's final matrix is a transformation matrix which defines the bone in armature-space in the current pose (M1). I want to calculate this from other matrices, given a really simple armature with two bones, the second bone parented to the first.

```
armature = bpy.data.objects["Armature"]
M0 = armature.pose.bones[0].matrix       #final matrix for the first bone
M1 = armature.pose.bones[1].matrix       #final matrix for the second bone
```

A bone's bind-pose or rest-pose matrix is its transformation from the armature origin:

```
l0 = armature.data.bones[0].matrix_local
```

I can calculate the local rest matrix relative to the bone's parent:

```
l1 = armature.data.bones[1].matrix_local * l0.copy().inverted()
```

I can seem to calculate the final matrix of the first bone (M0) like this:

```
b0 = armature.pose.bones[0].matrix_basis    #local bone transform
l0*b0    #this equals M0
```

However, if I want to calculate the second bone's matrix, which is parented to the first, I can not get the same M1 matrix back while trying this:

```
b1 = armature.pose.bones[1].matrix_basis    #local bone transform
l0*b0*l1*b1    #I wanted to go through the parent chain like this but couldn't get back M1
```

However, the resulting matrix has the rotation part of M1, but the translation part is different.

The reason I want to do this to see how to do a bone hierarchy system for myself, but I seem to be missing something.

Comment: partially answered here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44975/7777 (does not include constraint calculation and IK)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this link. the difference between matrices is described here:

[https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44637/how-can-i-manually-calculate-bpy-types-posebone-matrix-using-blenders-python-ap](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/121495/61021)