# Get visual transform of object through python

Tags: python, scripting, armature

I'm trying to save transform matrices of objects into a text file using python. These objects are animated using armatures. I tried to use the "matrix_world" field but that only contains the base value. It's possible to do similar to a mesh which gives a transformed mesh (using the animations and modifiers, etc) but that does not contain the transformation matrix that I need.

Is is possible to get that transformation matrix which is used to render the mesh in the view (basically that matrix which is created using the base matrix plus the animations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your mesh is composed of multiple pieces that are posed with armature, the mesh itself has only 1 origin and 1 matrix transform.

To get the transformation of pieces you need to extract transformation of those pose bones.

You can use `bpy.data.objects["Armature"].pose.bones["Bone"].matrix` added to your armature global transform matrix or also you can use this answer:

[How can I manually calculate bpy.types.PoseBone.matrix](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44975/7777)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried that too, it turned out that I need both of the matrices and I need to multiply them to get the correct result (because the bone matrix contains rotation and position and the object matrix contains scale and base position).