# How do I Snap a pose bone to the other using python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a IK-FK switch, and Im having trouble to make the pose bone to snap to another bone. (With rotation and stuff)

I tried to do something like Bone1.matrix = Bone2.matrix but it doesn't seems to work.

What I want to achieve is something like copy transform constraint, but instead of constraint, is a one time snapping via python. I have try many things and search around, and nothing seems to be working for me. I hope I could get some luck asking for help here.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13yGv-U5joAzT0SheWNu3id7yAbvRtwz5/view?usp=sharing

Heres a link to my blend file if that helps.

Thank you very much

Comment: Recommend look in _`addons/rigify/rig_ui_template.py`_ there are a number of snapping routines.  Could use a temporary copy transform constraint in 2.8+ by running disable and keep constraint operator before removing.

Comment: I tried to apply copy transform constraint, but I couldnt "apply" the transformation, or i dont know how, and so after i remove the constraint, it doesnt do anything

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172919/bake-an-fcurve-with-visual-transforms/172973#172973

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108531/creating-a-generic-ik-fk-snap-script