# What's the differences between posebone's vector and bone's vector?

Tags: python, armature, bones, pose-mode

I want to get a certain bone's head/tail coords in world space in **pose mode**. I've seen some answers about Bones.vector and PoseBone.vector.
When I set different frame of the armature, the PoseBone.vector is changing while Bone.vector never changes.
So I wonder the differences between them and how to get a bone's head/tail coords in world space.

Comment: i am not totally sure but i think the bone's vector is the one which you set in edit mode (so this is AFAIK the rest position) and the pose position is the current pose position, so maybe you can say the "animated" position? Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks i understand what you mean. But i still wonder how to get a bone's head/tail position in world space. In pose mode, different from Bone, PoseBone do not have head_local or tail_local to describe position in armature local coords, just only PoseBone.head and PoseBone.tail which is relative to the parent. Is there anything can provide some position information?

Comment: maybe this helps you? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109815/how-can-i-move-a-posebone-to-a-specific-world-space-position

Comment: That's exactly what i want. Appreciate!